# How can I access the internet?

Tags: internet

My boyfriend installed Ubuntu on my computer but I cannot open the web browser to get to the internet, because I can't find the blue E icon in the main screen.

I know that the internet connection works because I am surfing right now from my computer, but I can only do this because the browser was left open.

How do I launch a browser so I can see web pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Big Blue 'E' is Internet Explorer on Windows, which is a web browser.  Ubuntu does not run Internet Explorer, but has several other browsers available to access the internet.  Common ones include Firefox and Chromium, and Google Chrome.

Look for an Icon on the desktop that looks like a blue circle with an orange fox wrapped around the bottom - this is Firefox.  You can use it to access the internet.  Alternatively, press the 'special' key on your keyboard (probably looks like a windowpane) and type firefox, which will cause your computer to search for firefox.

The default icons for various browser on Ubuntu include:

- Firefox [image: firefox icon]
- Chromium[image: chromium icon]

Comment: thank you ! so there is no blue e anymore? I don't like the red icon. I found the orange fox in the left side and it works! (it doesnt look like a fox) =]

Comment: No, the Blue-e is pretty much restricted to Windows operating systems.

Comment: @Wilf - thanks!  I was feeling way too lazy to upload the icons

Comment: @CharlesGreen +1 i would of been to lazy to explain the icons...